# Excel dotm file does not work on other PCs

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I have a weird problem. I created a VBA-add-in based on the tutorial given [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg597509(v=office.14)).
I followed all the instructions to the T and it works beautifully on my PC. So I decided to test it on other PCs. While the VBA add-in gets recognized, when I click on the add-in button, the macro does not run.

I get the following popup.

[image: Error on MS word]

I checked and double-checked the Trust Center settings. I also checked if all the check-points in the following [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/the-macro-cannot-be-found-or-has-been-disabled/58c67454-235a-4d24-a77a-10e6995aca04) are also taken care.

Now, the macro exists, but can only run from my PC. Help me resolve this error please.

Comment: Check this file references. If there exists some reference to another file - remove it and copy all macro into your file.

Comment: Hello Akina, Thanks for your response. I am not referring to other files from this macro. I read comments on the given word doc and update to another excel sheet. The macro code is based on this example: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/export-word-review-comments-in-excel/54818c46-b7d2-416c-a4e3-3131ab68809c?page=4

Comment: (Shot in the dark) Will the macro run on another machine if you save it in a `DOCM` file instead of a `DOTM`?